# VB6 MS DATAGRID CONTROL "The Current Row Is not Avaiable"

Tags: vb6

I have datagrid using adodb (not adodc) when user double click record from The datagrid, record will appear on the label. but when user close the form. there is an error

> Ms Datagrid control / The Current row isn't avaiable

I don't know what is wrong, I have already close the recordset while form unload

this is my code

```
Dim myrecordset As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub dtgrid_DblClick()
Label9.Caption = ""
Label9.Caption = dtgrid.Columns(0)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Call ConnectDB
With myrecordset
.ActiveConnection = con
'.LockType = adLockReadOnly
.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.Open "SELECT * FROM Foo "
End With
Set dtgrid.DataSource = myrecordset
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
myrecordset.close
set myrecordset = nothing
Call CloseDB
End Sub
```

this is from module

```
Public function CloseDB
    Set CMD = Nothing 'adodb command
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing 'adodb connection
end sub
```

Comment: Can you post code for `CloseDB` function, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you closed the recordset and the datasource still is pointing to it.  Try setting the DataSource property to nothing before closing the recordset.

Comment: Interesting.  Someone downvoted the answer a year later when it was the correct one.